# Spark Error: I/O error constructing remote block reader. java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException at java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

The execution was ok locally in unit test, but fails when the Spark Streaming execution is propagated to the real cluster executors, like they silently crash and no longer available for the context:

```
stream execution thread for kafkaDataGeneratorInactiveESP_02/Distance [id = 438f45a0-acd6-4729-953f-5a18ae208f1f, runId = a98c6d39-fe14-4ed5-b7fe-7e4009de51b2]] impl.BlockReaderFactory (BlockReaderFactory.java:getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(765)) - I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:656)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:2940)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:822)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:575)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:829)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
        at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CommitLog.deserialize(CommitLog.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CommitLog.deserialize(CommitLog.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.get(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.$anonfun$getLatest$2(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:190)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcVJ$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcVJ$sp.java:23)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofLong.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:258)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:300)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
```

First thing I have tried was changing the query name, having slash and space: `kafkaDataGeneratorInactiveESP_02/Distance`

After repacing it to the correct one in

```
.queryName("kafkaDataGeneratorInactive" + currentIter.metadata.getString("label"))
```

100% proven from having / or space in the string, the error hasn't gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the failure was actually in using the same name for the query name and checkpoint location path (but not in the part that was attempteed to be improved for the first time). Later I have fount one more error log:

```
2021-12-01 15:05:46,906 WARN  [main] streaming.StreamingQueryManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(69)) - Stopping existing streaming query [id=b13a69d7-5a2f-461e-91a7-a9138c4aa716, runId=9cb31852-d276-42d8-ade6-9839fa97f85c], as a new run is being started.
```

Why the query was stopped? That's because in Scala I was creating streaming queries in a loop, iterating the collection, while keeping all the query names and all the checkpoint names the same. After making them unique (i just used the string values from the collection), the failure problem has gone.